# Why can't I share (personal 365) OneDrive files with people signed into a work account?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, onedrive, microsoft-onenote

I am trying to share files (and OneNote's) from my **personal** (Office 365) OneDrive account. If the recipient isn't signed in at all, it works fine. If the recipient is signed into a personal Microsoft account, it also works fine. **However,** if they are signed into a work or school account, the following happens:

- **If they are on desktop:** it displays a error saying "Something went wrong. Please try again or refresh the page. 403" (pictured at the end of post)
- **If they are on mobile:** it displays an error saying "Link can't be opened in the OneDrive app. Do you want to open it in your browser," and if you agree it will just redirect you back into the OneDrive app and you'll get the same error. Forcing it to open in the browser results in an error too (if they are signed in on a work account in browser).

This happens if I make the link fully public (no sign in required), and if I make it private (give that specific person access only).

Is this a bug in OneDrive? Or is there something I need to change in order to make this work?

[image: OneDrive: Dropped ice cream graphic with text "Something went wrong"]

These are the sharing settings I am using when sending these links
[image: OneDrive sharing settings]

Comment: It may be because Microsoft defines these two types of accounts differently, so it restricts the sharing of files with each other.

Comment: Your Personal OneDrive account and your Work OneDrive account are part of entirely different tentants. On a more personal note, you really shouldn't be using your Personal accounts for Work, if you need remote access to your Work account have your IT Administrator make the required changes to their infrastructure.

Comment: So yeah, but if a link is *publicly* accessible, as in, unauthenticated users can access it. Then I feel like all signed-in users should be able to access it too. Also @Ramhound, I don’t have a work account, I’m trying to share files with my accountant who uses a business account. He needs to sign-out to access anything I send him.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted microsoft support about this. They confirmed this is a limitation of OneDrive, it's not possible to share anything between OneDrive personal and OneDrive business - even if the sharing options say "Anyone".

I have created a ticket on feedback hub for this problem, if anyone else is frustrated by this, please vote on it here to get Microsoft's attention.

https://aka.ms/AAkhjcm

Comment: I tried to access the link. It redirects me to the feedback hub app, which says "Your account doesn't have access to this feedback." Probably the same reason :D Well done, Microsoft.